# using 2 pagers in a single views slideshow

Tags: drupal

So I'm trying to add a 2nd pager to a slideshow created in views; the functionality of this is to act as arrows on wither side of the images in the slide show to go through it. I already have another on the bottom to indicate what page your on(the small grey dot example).

I realize I'm not the best at articulating my question's well, if you need any more detail, please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Are you not using ajax in your slideshow? You are asking how to have pager work on 2 views regardless of the application, right?

Comment: I do have ajax enabled. What I'm asking is essentially how would I go about adding a "next" and "back" image/link and have a "grey dot" indicator at the bottom of the images at the same time.

Comment: probably the easiest thing to do is use a plugin that does that for you. There are many. Aside that, you can style the pager as you need. Dots though, you will need to get the count total for that.

Comment: Is there one you would recommend off the top of your head?

Comment: Not specifically. I always just made them myself. I never used a pager for them though. I would have the view select all then run some basic PHP processing before display and build my own slider and dot system in jquery. My slideshows typically don't load in more than 5 or 10 images though so concern for resources or load times was always a non issue

Comment: Thank you Kai for your help, I in fact figured out a solution to my issue; again thank you for dealing with my questions.